# Generic XML accumulator Java 8

Tags: java, xml, visitor-pattern, accumulator

I have to process a lot of information of a certain type. So an xml accumulator might fit well into my use case. So whenever I encounter xml such as:

```
<Currency1>
    //... 
</Currency1>
```

I would add it to some sort of container or `list` or whatever. So after processing, the accumulator should contain something like this:

```
<Currencies>
    <Currency1>
        // et cetera
    </Currency1>
    <Currency2>
        // et cetera
    </Currency2>
    <Currency3>
        // et cetera
    </Currency3>
</Currencies>
```

How can I accomplish this with Java 8? I don't want to just use the native java Collections framework

Edit: The code is a bit complicated so I reduced it down to this

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
if (formsContext != this.NULL)
{
    if(dataTemplate.hasCurrencyPayload())
    {
        l.add(dataTemplate.getCurrencyPayload().toString())
    }
    this.processForms(dataTemplate, plForm, formsContext, fModel);
}
```

The place of interest is the final `if` condition where I I check to see if the dataTemplate contains a currency payload, if it does I just add it to a String list. Not very robust :(

Comment: Could you just use List<?> and then just add a root tag to the accumulation?

Comment: @arabian_albert I'm looking for something more robust. I don't want to just use the collections framework

Comment: last `if` condition is where I just add to a String list. But this probably isn't the best thing. Maybe someone has a better way?